# Chronological data model

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, datamodel

On the twitter website if you click on the connect tab on the top of the screen (https://twitter.com/i/connect)  you get this nice little chronological display of your tweets and when new people followed you, etc.

I'm curious what could be the data model behind this to allow them to build a UI like this. I'm trying to recreate it on my own and was wondering if anybody had an idea what it could be? For example, modeling connections between people seems trivial enough, you can use some type of graph, but then being able to keep track of dates when you added somebody or somebody un-followed you seems non-trivial. Any ideas?

Comment: Every action has a timestamp.  StackOverflow does the same thing. :)

Comment: but what about unfollowing someone???